# Is it possible to configure a fall back queue (button) in Live Agent (Native)?

Tags: liveagent

I have going through the documentation and can't find any clear information on setting up a fa ll back queue.

Example: In a French support page, if no French agents are available to chat and English agents are available, display a button indicating that English agents are available and give the option to the user to launch an English chat.

Has anyone worked on something like this?

Thanks

Comment: You can add logic on your page which checks if the French button is rendered and if not renders the English button based on availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be very simple.

liveagent.showWhenOnline('buttonid',document.getElementById('button container id'));